# How to sync a database field's content with a text file's content?

Tags: database, svn, content-management-system, synchronization

Here's the situation: we're building our own CMS, and what the boss wants is using a system like Dropbox (local), in order to synchronize the content of CMS documents with the developer's local text files (Something like using SVN, but instead of using File system to store the content of the CMS document's source code, use the DB). We're using MS SQL Server 2005 to store the content, and that's where the tricky part is: how to edit a text file, save it and it appears in the required database field.

The following T-SQL technique could be the solution: [The TSQL of Text Files](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-tsql-of-text-files/)

But the boss said 'avoid using this, and any other text-file-to-db, db-to-text-file technique'. So he wants something already done, simply to skip the logging in the CMS and editing the CMS document, instead edit a local file, save it and .. done.

It sounds impossible to me (if we don't use the T-SQL technique), I did a 2 week research before writing this, but it's worth a shot, you're the bests here.

Comment: A colleague went to a SQL2012 demo where this was demo'd as a new feature. A shared folder, drop your files in there and they're saved to SQL

Comment: That will be cool, thanks for the quick answer, but our company sticks to MS SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0):

Write a client application to get the text file process it and synchronize it with database. like an intermediate program.